# Application launched on menu creation

Tags: android, tabs, barcode

I'm using an application to read QR code (Barcode) in an application i'm developping. My problem is that I don't want barcode to be launched at the menu creation (A TabActivity). 
To be clear : I create the menu that way

```
public void createMenu(int current) {
    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;   // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Scan.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("scanner").setIndicator(null,res.getDrawable(R.drawable.barcode_scan)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Research.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("research").setIndicator(null,
                              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.system_search))
                              .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
```

and, in the Scan class, I have the following :

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    setContentView(R.layout.scan);
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE"); // "PRODUCT_MODE for bar codes
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android");
        Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,marketUri);
        startActivity(marketIntent);

    }
}
```

But, at the cration of the menu, the Barcode application is launch each time, skipping the menu displaying even if if select a current tab that is not the scanner one. How to fix that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
       @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        setContentView(R.layout.scan);
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE"); // "PRODUCT_MODE for bar codes
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android");
            Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,marketUri);
            startActivity(marketIntent);

        }
}
```

Change this as

@Override

```
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    setContentView(R.layout.scan);

}
```

Comment: I changed the onStart method to onResume and that's working. Is it a good idea or a bad trick ?